# Mongoose crash after 2/3 updates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As I understand it, for a correct RESTfull API, you should send a separate request for each document to be updated.

In this case, I'm working on a user import function. And it parses the first 2 users correctly, but fails on the third one.

These requests are sent using Restangular using a forEach that iterates over an array of users that should be imported.

Function:

```
    /** ----------------------------------- *
     * importUser
     * @param req
     * @param res
     * ------------------------------------ */
    function importUser(req, res) {

        var data = req.body,
            User = new models.User({}),
            user = {},
            ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
        var usrId = new ObjectId( (typeof data.id !== 'undefined' && data.id.length < 12) ? "123456789012" : data.id );

        user.firstname = data.firstname;
        user.lastname = data.lastname;
        user.email = data.email.toLowerCase();

        var pass = new models.Passport({});
        pass.provider = "local";
        pass.token = "";
        pass.makeSalt();
        pass.hashedPassword = pass.encryptPassword(data.password);

        user.passports = pass;

        User.update( { 'email':user.email}, user,{ upsert : true }, function(err,docs){
                if(err) {
                    res.status(400).send(new UserError('INVALID_USER_DATA'));
                }else {
                    res.send(docs);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

Log:

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55d72ccc409102491250a5db") }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55d72ccc409102491250a5db") }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("55d72ccc409102491250a5db") }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("55e08d5589dcd76226d32efd") }) { '$set': { email: 'smiley86@gmail.com' } } { passports: { hashedPassword: 'AsxcJSxIH7wZ+IF3I+X6BZiPKtgqIzxA5KgnmSLpVgPhzRtE1apxD1i6EqXFDxOpO1kvMiVWtkrW8doH2KxrJg==', salt: 'YreiOZjcVoAtmqUbZV7YVg==', token: '', provider: 'local', id: '55e08d5789dcd76226d32efe', obj_type: 'passport' }, email: 'smiley86@gmail.com', lastname: 'Hedin', firstname: 'Mikael' } 
Mongoose: users.update({ _id: ObjectId("55e08d5789dcd76226d32eff") }) { '$set': { email: 'john.doe@exempel.se' } } { passports: { hashedPassword: '1Pw6KjikpmrhH9CWlNZCeDbZWcOTI5y57oK/qW0tu04h2nmN/cUIcyJdl8nwYdVFKXO3rf2do1eN89FeQcfV6g==', salt: 'qOdXvaszh2wtx6oBPkUORw==', token: '', provider: 'local', id: '55e08d5789dcd76226d32f00', obj_type: 'passport' }, email: 'john.doe@exempel.se', lastname: 'Doe', firstname: 'John' } 
/Users/mikael/Sites/api-server-models/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2001
  oldCb(error, result ? result.result : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 });
  ^
TypeError: object is not a function
at Query.callback (/Users/mikael/Sites/api-server-models/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2001:7)
at /Users/mikael/Sites/api-server-models/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
at /Users/mikael/Sites/api-server-models/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

req.body:

```
{ firstname: 'Mikael',lastname: 'Hedin', password: 'mikael', email: 'smiley86@gmail.com', organization: 'Runic Design', token: '<JSON JWT token for authentication>' }
```

new models.User({}):

```
{ passports: [], status: 2, telephone: [], obj_type: 'user' }
```

UserSchema (retrieved in model.User({})):

```
UserSchema.add({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        index: {unique: true},
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: [validateEmail, 'INVALID_USER_EMAIL']
    },
    telephone:[TelephoneSchema],
    organization: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        default: 2
        /*
         * 0 - removed
         * 1 - deactivated
         * 2 - draft/uncomfirmed
         * 3 - activated
         */
    },
    passports: [PassportSchema],
    expDate:{
        type: Date
    },
    loginAt:{
        type: Date
    }
});
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it throws this error on the last request... their all identical

Comment: can you give me all the input data that you're request for the update.

Comment: Updated with req.body and what the models.User({}) returns.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using mongoose you should define your dicument or Object because the purpose using mongoose is to deliver Object Data Model correctly to your database.

I have similar code like you did but different structure :

My **User.js** Object Data Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// set up a mongoose model
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    _id : {type : String, unique : true},
    username: String,
    email : String,
    password: String,
    gcmID :String,
    gender : String
}));
```

and here is my code when calling the user Object Model :

```
var User  = require('../model_data/User');

var register = {

    registergcmSecond : function (req,res){
        //get id req.body to a variable and check it one by one
        var gcmID  = req.body.gcmID || '';
        var uidUser = req.body.uidUser || '';
        //check your your variable to make sure is not null
        if(gcmID &&uidUser){
            User.update({ _id : uidUser },{gcmID : gcmID}, function (err, user){
                if(err){
                    res.json({
                        status : "not_ok",
                        result : "Failed query",
                        resultType : serverConst.ErrorQuery
                    });
                }else{
                    res.json({
                        status : "ok",
                        result : "Document Updated",
                        resultType : serverConst.RegisterGcm
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

and if you are stuck and have no idea what the structure looks like you can visit this website : http://thejackalofjavascript.com/architecting-a-restful-node-js-app/

Comment: The document/model is defined in a separate file, You can see me calling it with the 'User' variable.  `User = new models.User({}),`